# GRUB Error 22 after accidentally deleting Ubuntu partition from XP's disk management

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I accidentally deleted the linux partition on a system that dual boots with XP

Now when I boot I get

```
Grub Error 22
```

I can't remember which version of Ubuntu I had - it's either 8.10 or 9.04

I can't boot to any of the Live disks for 8.10. 9.04 or 9.10 but I caN boot to live disk for 10.10 (1 out of 6 times with Grub error on the other attempts)

I've tried burning SuperGrubDisk to CD but it doesn't boot, I get `Grub Error 17`. I also tried gParted but can't boot to the CD - there was some error message not being able to mount stuff.

Anyone know how to fix this? I don't know What version of Grub I have

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends entirely on what you are looking to do. Did you want to reinstall Ubuntu? If so, probably the easiest way of getting it all up and working again is to go through the live install on your 10.10 disk. Just make sure that you don't accidentally wipe your XP partition. It should reinstall Grub and reconfigure it for you to have entries for both your XP partition and the newly installed Linux partition.

Booting to the live disks should NOT give you grub errors, regardless of what version of Ubuntu you are running...these disks should boot straight from CD, and therefore not check your boot record. Are you sure you were booting to CD first? Are you sure the disks aren't damaged in some way? Or, if you're not dead set on 8 or 9, try using 10.04, 10.10, or 11.04(beta).

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped - although due to one or two other small problems with the machine, I've decided to use a USB caddy to get the data off the HDD - then I will nuke it - :)

Comment: The key is multiple partitions / HDDs. Keep your data elsewhere, that way, if anything happens to your OS's partition, you don't have fret to much about nuking it and starting over again. This is a lesson I'm just learning after many, many years of having to try and recover lost data.